# React жалуется на файл который никогда не существовал

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

На занятиях по React пишем сайт, и когда мы делали данные для [image: введите сюда описание изображения]корзины, сайт стал ругаеться на файл Main.js которого никогда не было, хотя у других все воркает. Как исправить?

Comment: Если ругается, значит где то у вас он прописан, например в импорте

Comment: main.js это файл который создается при build. Но не Main.js. Main.js где-то прописан у Вас. Еще попробуйте переместить проект в путь без кирилицы.